# How to use SelectFromModel with cross_validate in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, artificial-intelligence, cross-validation

I am trying to use SelectFromModel to select features from my dataset before training a DecisionTreeClassifier model. I am also using cross_validate to evaluate the model performance. However, I am not sure how to use these two functions together.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate


# Split the dataset into features and target
X = dataset.drop('target_column', axis=1)  # Remove 'target_column' with the actual target column name
y = dataset['target_column']

# Feature selection using SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier)
selector = SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42))
X = selector.fit_transform(X, y)
num_selected_features = X.shape[1]
print(f'Number of Features Selected: {num_selected_features}')

# train a DecisionTreeClassifier with specificity as the evaluation metric
classifier = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy",
                                   min_samples_split=5,
                                   random_state=0)

# Cross-validate the model using specificity as the evaluation metric
cross_validation_results = cross_validate(estimator=classifier,
                                        X=X,
                                        y=y,
                                        cv=5,
                                        scoring="accuracy",
                                        return_train_score=True)

# Print the cross-validation results
print(cross_validation_results)
```

Comment: Do you need specificity metric as evaluation metric?

Answer (score 0):

- `make_pipeline` function is used to create a pipeline that consists of two steps: `SelectFromModel` and `DecisionTreeClassifier`. The SelectFromModel step performs feature selection using a RandomForestClassifier, and the DecisionTreeClassifier step trains the decision tree model.
- By passing the pipeline (pipeline) to the cross_validate function, the entire pipeline will be evaluated using cross-validation.
- Since you mentioned you need `specificty` as metric, defined a dictionary `scoring` that specifies "Specificity" as the scoring metric using make_scorer.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectFromModel
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, specificity_score

# Split the dataset into features and target
X = dataset.drop('target_column', axis=1)  # Remove 'target_column' with the actual target column name
y = dataset['target_column']

# Create a pipeline with feature selection and model training
pipeline = make_pipeline(
    SelectFromModel(RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)),
    DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion="entropy", min_samples_split=5, random_state=0)
)

# Define the scoring metric
scoring = {'Accuracy': 'accuracy', 'Specificity': make_scorer(specificity_score)}

# Cross-validate the pipeline
cross_validation_results = cross_validate(estimator=pipeline,
                                          X=X,
                                          y=y,
                                          cv=5,
                                          scoring=scoring,
                                          return_train_score=True)

# Print the cross-validation results
print(cross_validation_results)
```

- Now, the cross-validation results will include the specificity score for each fold.